# (io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroDataConfig:370) Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hamcrest/Matcher

Tags: java, confluent-platform, ksqldb, hamcrest

I am running ksql-tests via command line and I get this error. I tried adding jar manually to classpath before running tests, but still shows this error.

How can I run ksql-test-runner via command line. I am using Confluent 7.5.1 KSQL container

`$ ksql-test-runner --sql-file ksql-statements.ksql --input-file input.json --output-file output.json`

````
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hamcrest/Matcher
        at io.confluent.ksql.test.tools.TestCaseBuilder.createTest(TestCaseBuilder.java:135)
        at io.confluent.ksql.test.tools.TestCaseBuilder.buildTests(TestCaseBuilder.java:97)
        at io.confluent.ksql.test.tools.KsqlTestingTool.runWithTripleFiles(KsqlTestingTool.java:132)
        at io.confluent.ksql.test.tools.KsqlTestingTool.main(KsqlTestingTool.java:56)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hamcrest.Matcher
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:527)
        ... 4 more```
````

Comment: Hamcrest typically is not added as a runtime depdency. The container could be packaged bad. Previously releases of Confluent Platform had similar issues with Guava

Comment: @OneCricketeer what could be a solution for it?

Comment: You could try manually adding hamcrest jar files to the classpath. Or downgrade ksql, or contact Confluent Support for a proper fix

Comment: It seems you have to downgrade the version or double check the libraries you need to add to the classpath. Starting in version 5.3.0, ksql-test-runner throws a ClassNotFoundException: https://docs.confluent.io/5.4.11/ksql/docs/developer-guide/ksql-testing-tool.html#provide-required-jar-files